# Selecting the last (closest) element with specific child only with XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0

I need to check all elements to see if there is a preceding element (not always a sibling) that has any PI element. If so, I need to assign an attribute to all following elements **UNTIL** the next PI element is found.

Example XML Input:

```
<chapter id = "1">
<section>
<heading>some text here</heading>
<p>some text here<?Test1?></p>
</section>
<section>
<heading>some text here</heading>
<p>some text here<?Test2?></p>
</section>
</chapter>
<chapter id="2">
<section>
<p></p>
</section>
</chapter>
```

In this example, the chapter element with the id = "2" should get an attribute named "test2" and then stop (so it should not also get "test1".

What I have now:

```
 <xsl:key name="test1PIs" match="*[not(self::main|self::title)]/processing-instruction('test1')"   use="following::*/@id"/>

    <xsl:key name="test2PIs" match="*[not(self::main|self::title)]/processing-instruction('test2')"      
        use="following::*/@id"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="*">          
       <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:if test="key('test1PIs',@id)">
                <xsl:attribute name="test1"/>           
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="key('test2PIs',@id)">
                <xsl:attribute name="test2"/>           
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>  
    </xsl:template>
```

What I end up with:

```
<chapter id="2" test1="" test2="">
**child elements here**
</chapter>
```

What I really want:

```
<chapter id="2" test2="">
**child elements here**
</chapter>
```

@Michael Kay's response got me where I needed to be.  In final:

```
<xsl:template match="*">          
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:variable name="piParent" 
                select="preceding::processing-instruction()[1]"/>
            <xsl:if test="$piParent">
                <xsl:attribute name="processPI">
                    <xsl:value-of select="name($piParent)"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>  
    </xsl:template>
```

It works by assigning an attribute to all elements following a specific PI until it reaches another PI.

Comment: I don't follow your logic, Chris. Can you edit your question to include an example of what you _do_ want as output?

Comment: It has been edited. Please note, I phrased the problem in basic terms as adding too much information makes it confusing. I just need to copy the closest PI above each element to an attribute...all levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like:

```
    <xsl:template match="*">          
       <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:variable name="piParent" 
                 select="preceding::*[processing-instruction()][1]"/>
            <xsl:if test="$piParent">
              <xsl:attribute name="name($piParent/processing-instruction())"/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>  
    </xsl:template>
```

However, I'm guessing a little because you haven't specified the task very clearly.

Comment: Thank you @Michael Kay.  I apparently had been dancing around the solution for a while now but missing small bits.  Your response got me what I needed.   I edited it a little bit (included above). Thanks again!